# How to create trigger in Oracle that computes derived value

Tags: sql, oracle

Create a trigger to compute the value of the duration column when a tuple is inserted in ContractInfo .

```
ContractInfo Table
HAS_CONTRACT          DATE_FROM DATE_TO     DURATION
--------------------- --------- --------- ----------
Simon Palm            20-AUG-01 19-AUG-02          0
Simon Palm            20-SEP-02 19-AUG-03          0
Flut                  10-JUN-99 09-SEP-02          0
```

How can I make a trigger? I am a bit confused with the trigger.

Comment: What type of SQL?  Triggers are implementation-specific.

Comment: Have you [tried anything](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Which RBDMS is this for?  Also, I'm assuming that this is a homework assignment and you have to match this requirement... because otherwise a computed column would probably make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger ContractInfo_buifer
  2  before insert or update on contractinfo
  3  for each row
  4  declare
  5  begin
  6    :new.duration := :new.date_to - :new.date_from; -- answer in days.
  7  END;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into ContractInfo (HAS_CONTRACT,  DATE_FROM, DATE_TO ) values ('Simon Palm', to_date('20-AUG-01', 'dd-mon-rr'), to_date('19-AUG-02', 'dd-mon-rr'))
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> select * from contractinfo;

HAS_CONTRA DATE_FROM DATE_TO     DURATION
---------- --------- --------- ----------
Simon Palm 20-AUG-01 19-AUG-02        364
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it with Oracle :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_ContractInfo
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ContractInfo REFERENCING
    NEW AS NEW
    OLD AS OLD
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    /* ON INSERT STATEMENTS */
  END IF;
  IF UPDATING THEN
    /* ON UPDATE STATEMENTS */
  END IF;
  /* COMMON STATEMENTS */
END;
/
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit of this sql query? Thank you

Comment: Why do you need the referencing clause? (I don't know why anyone needs it but it seems especially pointless here as you're not renaming anything).

Comment: @Ben: Definitely pointless unless you're telling this to someone who seems not to know anything about PL/SQL. So here I came up with my TRIGGER template which I usually start from when need to code one.
This was only a cue for the guy on how to proceed, the simplest way, in case he would have been on Oracle.
I can see it frustrated you, well, I understand, and I offer you a little hug to help you sleep better my dear.